# What does delegate registration mean in a conference?

Tags: conference, terminology

I saw on a conference website that the "delegate registration is up to the end of March".
I'm wondering what that "delegate" really means?

Answer (score 5):

Usually, this definition is extended to all the attendees of a conference, not just the presenters. So the delegate registration would be for anybody wanting to attend the conference

Comment: In some conferences, only registered participants (with a badge) are allowed in to hear the presentations or view the posters.

Comment: @GEdgar: In my field, this applies to all conferences, and while it may be different in other fields, now I wonder: What significance does a "registration" have if its purpose is not to determine who is allowed in to hear presentations?

Comment: @ORMapper: At smaller, informal conferences, registration serves  mainly to help the organizers plan (how large a room do we need, how much coffee, etc), and to let participants know who they can expect to meet there. There may not be any fee. In such cases, registration may be requested as a courtesy, but if you just show up without registering they won't keep you out.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you are talking about a computer science conference, this most likely means that for every accepted paper, one of the authors should be registered by the deadline in order not to get the paper removed from the program (and the proceedings). The presenting author would then be the "delegate" of the group of authors.

If it is already known that the paper will be presented by a non-author, then the respective person should also be registered by that date.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of an event there are a few things to consider. First
it may depend on the "type of event" for example: conference, summit, symposium, forum, expo. But typically it is referring to someone who registered for the event. A delegate is usually used at an association or membership event. There usually consist of a membership overall. However I have seen delegate used to describe someone with the basic attendee level. For example: delegate, premium, vip, sponsor etc. I've also seem delegate used instead attendee. This is a tricky one because there seems to be no consistent way.